# How to create a class that may return null?

Tags: c#, class

I'm stuck in creating a `class` that may or may not return a `null` value.

note:
I know that I can get around this by checking whether `File.Exists` before creating the instance (using the "alternative" block that is specific for this code), but just curious if I can...

Sample code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
...

internal class FormMain : Form {
    ...
    private MyClass myClass = null;
    private readonly String fileName = "/path/to/file/file.name";
 
    public FormMain() {
        /*
        // alternative
        if (File.Exists(fileName) {
            myClass = new MyClass(fileName);
            Setup();
            DoStuff();
        }
        */
        if ((myClass = new MyClass(fileName)) != null) {
            Setup();
            DoStuff();
        }
    }
    ...
}

internal class MyClass : IDisposable {
    // list of variables (all "String" type)
    ...
    public MyClass(String fileName) {
        if (File.Exists(fileName)) {
            // load file and initialize variables
        }
        /*
        // warning here when uncommented !!!
        else {
            return null;
        }
        */
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: All classes may or may not have `null` value (not return), I'm not sure if I get your question. It's not a return `null` thing, but more like an exceptional situation, like when the file is not found or the file you're trying to access is unavailable. In that case, you can throw an exception.

Comment: Well, I guess you can't return a null from a constructor, which makes sense somehow.
If something goes wrong you should probably raise an exception

Comment: Also, this is more like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @SᴇM: I accept, your XY analogy is correct for this specific case where I can check the existence of the file before instantiating the object. However, there may be some different cases (which I couldn't make up an example right now) where the coder can't check whether the object was created successfully or not.

Comment: @ssd If you don't want to create an object if a file does not exist, check it before creating it, and do not create if it does not exist. Calling a `new` operator shows the intention of creating an instance of that object, if it is somehow not possible, then it should throw an exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a factory method.

```
internal static MyClass ConstructMyClass(String fileName) {
        if (File.Exists(fileName)) {
            // load file and initialize variables and return an instance of MyClass
        }
        /*
        // warning here when uncommented !!!
        else {
            return null;
        }
        */
    }
```

Comment: I'll try it and then mark as answer. I admit, seemed reasonable to me.

Answer (score 1):

A `class` cannot return null, a class is only the definition of an object.

If you want object creation to fail, check for certain parameters in your constructor and `throw` an exception.

E.g.:

```cs
class MyClass {
    MyClass(object param) {
        if (param is string) {
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(param), "Parameter must not be string!");
        }
    }
}
```

Just make sure you document this behaviour so you don't shoot yourself in the foot.

Throwing here will prevent the memory from being allocated and the object from being created.

Edit: Peter's solution is more elegant, however if going that direction, I'd go for a Try-pattern:

```cs
bool TryConstructObject(out MyObject obj) {
     if (File.Exists(MyFile)) {
        obj = null;
        return false;
     }

     obj = new MyObject();
     return true;
}
```

Comment: `false` _if_ the file exists? Shouldn't the logic be inverse to that? `TryConstructObject` should also take a `MyFile` param.

Comment: This is just an example. Next time I'll add a notice down the bottom that this is just a step in the general direction ;)